# Eclipse Javadoc-like window for PHP

Tags: php, eclipse, phpdoc

I have a question about Eclipse which I'm starting to use as a PHP IDE. I'm not sure if the question is at the right place here.

Is there a window much like the Javadoc window where you can see all the information Eclipse has to offer about a certain PHP function or class?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used Eclipse as a PHP editor but I'm sure there's a plugin that can do that. Maybe [PHPEclipse](http://www.phpeclipse.com/).

I would recommend [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) for PHP editing, tho. It definitely contains the PHP language reference, as well as support for git, Smarty and plugins for just about anything else.

Comment: I've tried Netbeans, but I like the way Eclipse works.. Though missing a 'PHPdoc'-feature would be a good argument to switch back to Netbeans

Comment: Fair enough. Check out [PHPEclipse](http://www.phpeclipse.com/) then. That might have what you're looking for

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan I'm not so much interested in generating documentation for my own code. I just want to see function parameters and such of built-in functions.

Comment: @JochemKuijpers - NetBeans does exactly what you need and in addition for the documentation part. whether you are interested in it or not it's up to you ;)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're looking for is indeed available in the Eclipse PDT (PHP Development Tools) plugin.  Just hover over a class name, a method name, whatever, and if there has been any PHP docblock information in the code for that code element, then the hover popup will show it.  Further, native PHP functions will display the info from the PHP Manual.

Comment: Is there any way to lock this pop-up to a window? Because that is what I'm trying to do ;)

Comment: I've seen references to a "Generate Javadoc" command that will generate the HTML docs with the Javadoc content, so perhaps Eclipse is just displaying the HTML results of such a step.  The comparable option for PDT would be to manually run phpDocumentor, Doxygen, or some other doc generator program against your source code.  Any external program can be configured to run "like a command" from inside Eclipse by using the External Tools option.  It's even feasible for an External Tool to be specified as a Builder, thus run each time you save a file.